# On linux does calling yield immediately prompt a context switch?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

The question is whether a yield system call is immediately going to prompt a context switch or whether the scheduler will wait until the timer interrupt to do so.

Comment: Yes it does context switch immediately if there is any other candidate thread to switch to.

Comment: I see. So, timer interrupt is not the only case after which a context switch would take place. Are there other similar scenarios?

Comment: Absolutely. Many many others. Any blocking or IO call is likely to yield. sleep, read, write, select, pthread_mutex_lock, etc, etc...the list is way too long.

Comment: Interrupts - soft and hard - can also cause a switch.